# UPDATE Statement SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

In the picture below I have a table that I performed an INSERT query on. This SQL Query adds the information as new records. I want to add them to the records that already exist (as seen in the picture). Would that be possible? Maybe with an UPDATE Statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: table data view]

Current SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable
            (FormularyName,ClientName)
SELECT [Formulary Name],
       [Client Name]
FROM   FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 as F
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   mytable as M
               WHERE  F.formularyId = M.formularyId)
```

Comment: if you're appending existing records, then yes, use UPDATE

Comment: Did you try [searching for SQL Update](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20update)

Comment: I did but I am unsure how to modify the statement above to UPDATE the existing records.

Comment: Use the Graphic Interface to design your update. Then, if you really wish to write SQL in Access by hand, you'll have an example to show you the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable AS Imp
INNER JOIN FN_DataDump_ALL-02012015 AS F
    ON Imp.FormularyId = F.FormularyId
SET Imp.FormularyName = F.FormularyName,
    Imp.ClientName = F.ClientName
WHERE Imp.FormularyId = F.FormularyId
```

I didn't feel that joining `myTable` would be needed, but if you need to just add this before `SET`:

```
INNER JOIN myTable AS M
    ON F.formularyId = M.formularyId
```

If you do that you'll probably need to use some of those wonky parentheses from Access SQL, like this:

```
UPDATE ((ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable AS Imp
INNER JOIN FN_DataDump_ALL-02012015 AS F
    ON Imp.FormularyId = F.FormularyId)
INNER JOIN myTable AS M
    ON F.formularyId = M.formularyId)
SET Imp.FormularyName = F.FormularyName,
    Imp.ClientName = F.ClientName
WHERE Imp.FormularyId = F.FormularyId
```